# Cloudwatch Rules not getting triggered

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch

I have a lambda while logs whenever there is an exception while executing it. I can see the logs generated by lambda in cloudwatch -> Logs -> Log Groups -> aws/lambda/

I am trying to create a cloudwatch rule to capture any such exception and forward it to SNS / SQS topic. But whatsoever i try, cloud watch rule is not getting triggered.  I started with very basis rule

```
{
    "source": "aws.lambda.<my lambda name>"
}
```

I tried different combinations for the rule, but i don't see it working.

Is it something can be achieved via cloudwatch rules ?
Is there any other way to achieve this ?

My objective is to get notified whenever there an exception in lambda function.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use a Cloudwatch trigger not a rule.

This is a good tutorial on how to do it, scroll down to Step 4

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/get-notified-specific-lambda-function-error-patterns-using-cloudwatch/